# Can't delete file and folder in Ubuntu 16.04 with root access

Tags: linux, root, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to delete file 'lock' file in directory `/var/lib/apt/lists` with with sudo and with `sudo -s`, but system shows message that operation not permitted, also I can't open `/var/lib/apt/list/partial`, also operation not permitted. What's the reason of this problem?

Comment: Better question: Why are trying to do that? What problems are you trying to solve ?

Comment: Maybe the files are locked?

Comment: Does rebooting solve it?

Comment: rebooting doesn't solve it, files not locked, I can delete a and i atributes from file, also owner of lock file is root. I need to delete this file because I think this file block apt-get update command

Comment: Can you do `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`? And then update?